# Pika message consumption is slow while processing messages in callback function

Tags: python, rabbitmq, producer-consumer, xlrd, pika

I have a consumer application written in python. It consume the rabbitmq messages through multiprocessing. But when I try to process or validate those messages with in the on_message callback function then the consumption is bit slow. I am opening an excel mapping file to validate those incoming messages through a separate message class. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since I can't comment yet I ll write to you here what I think about the pub. I think your Question is not clear. Besides I think you should show some Code and explain further what you are trying to achieve. what is meant by consumption is a bit slow ? like how exactly ? and which Pika version are you using etc.. this can be Important to look up what can provoque this "slow" Error that you have. Besides I think Pika is buggy for the 0. version, while using it I had some issues sometimes and it is not thread safe.